# Include HTML component in Uibinder

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I would like to include some HTML codes in my gwt UiBinder. For example, put a navigation menu bar in a UiBinder as follows.

MenuBarBinder.ui.xml

```
<g:HTMLPanel>
    <div class="topnav">
        <a ui:field="home" class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
        <a ui:field="news" href="#news">News</a>
        <a ui:field="contact" href="#contact">Contact</a>
        <a ui:field="about" href="#about">About</a>
    </div> 
</g:HTMLPanel>
```

MenuBarBinder.java

```
public class MenuBarBinder extends Composite{

private static MenuBarBinderUiBinder uiBinder = GWT.create(MenuBarBinderUiBinder.class);

interface MenuBarBinderUiBinder extends UiBinder<Widget, MenuBarBinder> {
}

public MenuBarBinder() {
    initWidget(uiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
}
@UiField
//How can I refer the ui:field here?

}
```

How can I refer the ui:field in MenuBarUiBinder.java with @UiField?

Since HTML has more options on designing the UI than GWT widget, it would be very helpful to recommend a tutorial describing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the element is an anchor `<a>` then you would link that to a GWT `AnchorElement`:

```
<a ui:field="home" class="active" href="#home">Home</a>

...

@UiField AnchorElement home;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Then how can I convert the AnchorElement to Anchor? I need it to add the clickHandler.

Comment: use this constructor:   new Anchor(AnchorElement anchorElement)

Comment: @RobertNewton if you're referring to the protected Anchor constructor that is called by Anchor.wrap(Element), this is absolutely not intended for this use case _unless_ you have subclassed the widget, and are passing a fresh element in, or have already detached the element. Observe that Anchor.wrap will not work on a detached element, and a subclass will force you to reattach it if you want the event handlers to function.

Comment: @ColinAlworth thanks for pointing that out, I should have said Anchor.wrap(), not the constructor.  And like you say there are a few caveats with it.

Comment: @MingLeung in your *.ui.xml, have you considered using a <g:Anchor> widget tag instead of a <a> html element tag?  Then you can go "@UiField Anchor home".

Comment: In fact, which way is better? Leave it as html or using the gwt equivalent? What I am experiencing is that some html features are missing for the gwt equivalent. Or it is not simple to use.

Comment: Use the <g:Anchor> (and change g:HTML to g:HTMLPanel) is the only correct way so far - Anchor.wrap will appear to work _if you call it after the widget is attached_, but will not correctly attach/detach. The other correct way is to add the click handler to the HTML widget, and check the event to see if it came from the `<a>` tag (and which one, etc).

Comment: Personally, I would leave as HTML elements (<a> tag>) and do dynamic things (such as adding event handlers) using the elemental2 API.  e.g.  var homeAnchor = (HTMLAnchorElement) DomGlobal.document.getElementById("home");   homeAnchor.addEventListener("click", event -> { event handler });